# Extract portion of string jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex

```
<input type="text" name="data[546c8157fcc404ca04951022][5476bddb4a1bfef2128b4567][exp][apr]">
```

I want to extract second part of array and replace with `0`. how can do this?

**Expected output**

```
<input type="text" name="data[546c8157fcc404ca04951022][0][exp][apr]">
```

I tried replace and substring function but no luck. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(.*?\[[^\]]+\])\[[^\]]+\]
```

Try this.Replace by `$1[0]`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yR3mM3/47

```
var re = /^(.*?\[[^\]]+\])\[[^\]]+\]/gi;
var str = '<input type="text" name="data[546c8157fcc404ca04951022][5476bddb4a1bfef2128b4567][exp[apr]">';
var subst = '$1[0]';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
var element =  $('<input type="text" name="data[546c8157fcc404ca04951022][5476bddb4a1bfef2128b4567][exp][apr]">');

var parts = element.attr('name').split('][');
    parts[1] = 0;

element.attr('name', parts.join(']['));
```

Output:

```
<input type="text" name="data[546c8157fcc404ca04951022][0][exp][apr]">
```

Comment: It's work fine but affect in my form data. In my form hidden data which is not posted after applying this code.